# Parsing string to separate words by upper case letter, hyphen, and underscore

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that is concatenated which includes upper case letters, underscores, and hyphens that I need to parse out to individual words where each of those (upper case letter, underscore, hyphen) occur.

Running Python 3.7.0 using the re package.

Given this string: r1[3] = `person_firstName-Middle`

```
re.sub(r'((?<=[\_\-a-z])[\_\-A-Z]|(?<!\A)[\_\-A-Z](?=[\_\-a-z]))', r' \1', r1[3], flags=re.VERBOSE).lower()
```

Returns this: `person _first name -middle`

I need this: `person first name middle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a simple pattern and join the strings afterwards:

```
import re
myString='person_firstName-Middle'
output = re.findall('[A-Z]?[a-z]+',myString)
print(' '.join([word.lower() for word in output]))
#person first name middle
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the preprocessing leads to a string that has the format person_first name-middle name

```py
s = 'abc_John-Doe'
person = s.split('_')[0]
firstname = s.split('_')[1].split('-')[0]
middlename = s.split('_')[1].split('-')[1]
```

Comment: I agree with this one. A lot of times regex is completely overkill.  Except if he actually wants 'first' separate that is.

Comment: @Chris Albeit, a valid answer. Regex questions rarely deal with exact-match inputs as seen in the post. Providing fragile answers unless specifically requested is often followed by OP comments which sound like "but it fails for xyz, and what about this example."

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree 100%.  I should probably clarify that for those of us who do a lot of exploratory analysis the simpler approach is often better and I like seeing both methods represented.  To your point those who may not understand the pitfalls of one vs the other should probably lean towards the more fail-safe version.

Comment: I do agree that it was not a general solution, but I think I got carried away by the simplicity of the solution over the rigidity of it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem using only re.sub():

```py
import re
nameString = "person_firstName-Middle"
print(re.sub('[_-]|((?<!-)(?=[A-Z]))', ' ', nameString).lower())
```

should return:

```
person first name middle
```

The regular expression matches either with one of symbols "-" and "_" or with the space between any character that is not a "-" and a following upper case letter.
Then the matches are replaced by a space using re.sub().

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/XDE9eR/1) you can find a more detailed explanation of the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, using regex:

```
>>> r = "person_firstName-Middle"
>>> re.sub(r'([^_]+)_([^A-Z]+)([A-Z][^\-]+)\-', r'\1 \2 \3 ', r, flags=re.VERBOSE).lower()
'person first name middle'
```